# Kth element in transformed array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, bit-manipulation, xor

I came across this question in recent interview :

Given an array `A` of length `N`, we are supposed to answer `Q` queries. Query form is as follows :

Given `x` and `k`, we need to make another array `B` of same length such that `B[i] = A[i] ^ x` where `^` is XOR operator. Sort an array `B` in descending order and return `B[k]`.

Input format :
First line contains interger N
Second line contains N integers denoting array A
Third line contains Q i.e. number of queries
Next Q lines contains space-separated integers x and k

Output format :
Print respective B[k] value each on new line for Q queries.

e.g. 
for input :

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
2
2 3
0 1
```

output will be :

```
3
5
```

For first query,
`A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
For query `x = 2` and `k = 3`, `B = [1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2] = [3, 0, 1, 6, 7]`. Sorting in descending order `B = [7, 6, 3, 1, 0]`. So, `B[3] = 3`.

For second query,
`A` and `B` will be same as `x = 0`. So, `B[1] = 5`

I have no idea how to solve such problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are four steps. 1) Create the new array, `B`, that's the same size as `A`. 2) Populate `B`. For each `i` in `A`, `B[i] = A[i] ^ x;` 3) Sort `B`. 4) Return `B[k]`. Which part are you having trouble with? Can you show us some code and point out where your problem lies?

Comment: @JimMischel I believe something is missed out here. E.g. it must be done in place.

Comment: No, operations are not done in place. We need to make a separate array `B` same as `A` and then apply operations on `B` only.

Comment: As far as question is concerned, the number of queries asked were quite large in order to avoid brute force. I just can't find logic/way to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Ok, question is updated now.

Comment: Will there be multiple queries against a single array? That is, given an array A, will there be multiple queries of the form `x,k`? If so, please show a complete example.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple quesries. Question is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solvable in O(N + Q). For simplicity I assume you are dealing with positive or unsigned values only, but you can probably adjust this algorithm also for negative numbers.

First you build a binary tree. The left edge stands for a bit that is 0, the right edge for a bit that is 1. In each node you store how many numbers are in this bucket. This can be done in O(N), because the number of bits is constant.

Because this is a little bit hard to explain, I'm going to show how the tree looks like for 3-bit numbers [0, 1, 4, 5, 7] i.e. [000, 001, 100, 101, 111]

```
          *
     /         \
    2           3            2 numbers have first bit 0 and 3 numbers first bit 1
   / \       /     \ 
  2   0     2       1        of the 2 numbers with first bit 0, have 2 numbers 2nd bit 0, ...
 / \       / \     / \
1   1     1   1   0   1      of the 2 numbers with 1st and 2nd bit 0, has 1 number 3rd bit 0, ...
```

To answer a single query you go down the tree by using the bits of x. At each node you have 4 possibilities, looking at bit b of x and building answer a, which is initially 0:

1. b = 0 and k < the value stored in the left child of the current node (the 0-bit branch): current node becomes left child, a = 2 * a (shifting left by 1)
2. b = 0 and k >= the value stored in the left child: current node becomes right child, k = k - value of left child, a = 2 * a + 1
3. b = 1 and k < the value stored in the right child (the 1-bit branch, because of the xor operation everything is flipped): current node becomes right child, a = 2 * a
4. b = 1 and k >= the value stored in the right child: current node becomes left child, k = k - value of right child, a = 2 * a + 1

This is O(1), again because the number of bits is constant. Therefore the overall complexity is O(N + Q).

Example: [0, 1, 4, 5, 7] i.e. [000, 001, 100, 101, 111], k = 3, x = 3 i.e. 011

1. First bit is 0 and k >= 2, therefore we go right, k = k - 2 = 3 - 2 = 1 and a = 2 * a + 1 = 2 * 0 + 1 = 1.
2. Second bit is 1 and k >= 1, therefore we go left (inverted because the bit is 1), k = k - 1 = 0, a = 2 * a + 1 = 3
3. Third bit is 1 and k < 1, so the solution is a = 2 * a + 0 = 6

Control: [000, 001, 100, 101, 111] xor 011 = [011, 010, 111, 110, 100] i.e. [3, 2, 7, 6, 4] and in order [2, 3, 4, **6**, 7], so indeed the number at index 3 is 6 and the solution (always talking about 0-based indexing here).