# geting maximum number in a set with special conditions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, xor

I encountered a problem recently I have a hard time finding the answer.
**This is the question:**

Consider a set of numbers.There are tree kinds of input:

```
1 x
2 x
3
```

The first command adds integer **x** to the set.
The second one means for every element **y** in list, put:

```
y = y xor x
```

and The last command prints the biggest number in the set. for instance:

```
10
3
1 7
3
2 4
2 8
2 3
1 10
1 3
3
2 1
```

results:

```
0
7
15
```

if n is the number of commands in input:
[image]

 and: [image]

 also there is a 1 second execution time limit!

**My solution so far**:
lets call the set **S** and have an integer **m** which initially is 0.as you know:

```
number = number xor x xor x
```

meaning that if we apply **xor** twice on something then the its effect is reversed and the original number doesn't change. That being said if we every time we insert a number(command 1) we do the following:

```
y = y xor m
add y to S
```

and every time we want to get a number from the set:

```
find y
y = y xor m
return y
```

and if command two comes to the following:

```
m = m xor x
```

then the problem is almost solved, since initially save the XORed version of the numbers and when needed we do the revers!
But the problem here is to find the largest number in the set( pay attention that the numbers in the set are different from original numbers) so command 3 works right. I don't know how to do this in an efficient time.but I have an idea here:

 if we save the binary representation of the numbers in the set in a **trie** data structure at first the maybe we can quickly find the biggest number. I don't really know how but this idea occurred to me.
so to sum up these are my issues:

**problem 1:**

 how to find the biggest number in the revised list

**problem 2:**

 is this **trie idea** good?

**problem 3:**

 how can I implement it in code(the language is not very important here) so that it works time find?

also what is the time complexity needed to solve this problem in the first place?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your idea is correct, it can be solved in O(N log 10^9) using binary trie data structure.

The idea is to store numbers in binary notation yet putting biggest bits first, so while traversing the trie we can choose a branch that leads to greatest answer.

For determining which branch to choose we can determine this bit by bit, if from some trie node we have 2 branches with values 0 and 1 we choose the one which gives better result after xoring with m

Sample code (C++):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int Trie[4000005][2];
int nxt = 2;

void Add(int x)
{
    bitset<32>b(x);
    int c = 1;

    for(int j=31; j>=0; j--)
        if(Trie[c][b[j]])c=Trie[c][b[j]];
    else c = Trie[c][b[j]] = nxt++;
}

int Get(int x)
{
    bitset<32>b(x),res(0);
    int c = 1;

    for(int j=31; j>=0; j--)
        if(Trie[c][!b[j]])c=Trie[c][!b[j]],res[j]=!b[j];
    else c = Trie[c][b[j]], res[j]=b[j];

    return res.to_ullong()^x;
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    int q,m=0;
    cin>>q;
    Add(0);

    while(q--)
    {
        int type;
        cin>>type;
        if(type==1)
        {
            int x;
            cin>>x;
            Add(x^m);
        }
        else if(type==2)
        {
            int x;
            cin>>x;
            m^=x;
        }
        else cout<<Get(m)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this implantation is very close to the other answer in this  question but it seems the time complexity there is O(N). I'm a little confused. can you explain? thanks

Comment: also why is you trie of size 4000005 ?

Comment: @FarzinNasiri well time complexity is actually O(N log (maximum value)) and since maximum value is 10^9 log(maximum value) can be written as constant. For trie memory usage its hard to estimate how much memory it will consume, like first addition to trie will add maximum amount of new nodes(30) yet next one could add anywhere from 0 to 30 new nodes so i just picked a large constant that should be enough.

Comment: thanks so much but I worry that turning numbers to binary representation takes to much time if the number is big. and I'm using java so I have to write my own code to to make the number binary. is my concern right?

Comment: @FarzinNasiri well numbers are at most 10^9 so they have at most 30 bits so it is fast enough. I think java has some built in conversion, something like `Integer.toBinaryString(dec);` though you will need to pad resulting string with extra zeroes

Comment: @thanks,also I think there is a problem in your solution, as I mentioned we command 2 comes we have take the xor of all elements.how ever you code only takes the xor of the element it wants to print. I also noted in my question that for this we have to first xor then insert to trie. since its your code I don't know where to put this edit. Thank you for your great answers

Comment: @FarzinNasiri yeah I forgot we need to do that, updated my code, basically instead of inserting number x on query of type 1 you insert x^m.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487698/kth-element-in-transformed-array/58495041#58495041) and should be solvable in O(n), because the number of bits for `x` is constant (for 10^9 you will have to look at the 30 lowest bits).

1. At start `m = 0`, each time you encounter the 2nd command you do `m ^= x` (m = m xor x).
2. Use a binary tree. Unlike for the linked question the amount of numbers in a bucket doesn't matter, you just need to be able to tell if there is a number that has a certain bit which is one or zero. E.g. for 3-bit numbers 1, 4 and 5 the tree could look like this (left means bit is 0, right means bit is 1):

   ```
        *
      /   \
     1     1   there are numbers with highest bit 0 and 1
    /      /
   1      1    of the numbers with 1st bit 0, there is a number with 2nd bit 0 and ...
    \    / \
     1  1   1  of the numbers with 1st and 2nd bit 0, there is a number with 3rd bit 1,...
     1  4   5  (the numbers just to clarify)
   ```

   So adding a number just means adding some edges and nodes.
3. To get the highest number in the set you go down the tree and through the bits of m  and calculate the max `x` as follows:

   1. Initialize node `n` as the root of the tree, `i = 29` the bit of `m` we are looking at and the solution `x = 0`.
   2. `mi = (m & (1 << i)) >> i` (1 if the bit in `m` is 1, 0 otherwise).

      1. If we look at `n` and there is only an edge denoting a 0 or if `mi == 1` and we have a 0-edge: `n` becomes the node connected by that edge, `x = 2 * x + mi` (or more fancy: `x = (x << 1) | mi`).
      2. Otherwise `n` becomes the node connected by the 1-edge and `x = 2 * x + 1 - mi`
   3. If `i > 0`: decrease `i` by 1 and continue with step 2.

An example for 3-bit numbers m = 6 (110) and the numbers 1 (001), 4 (100) and 5 (101) in the set, the answer should be 7 (111), i.e. 1 xor 6: First step we go left and x = 1, then we can only go left and x = 3, then we can only go right and x = 7.